# Is HBase batch put put(List<Put>) faster than put(Put)? What is the capacity of a Put object?

Tags: hbase

I am working on a batch job to process a batch of Put objects into HBase through HTableInterface. There are two API methods, HTableInterface.put(List) and HTableInterface.put(Put).

I am wondering, for the same number of Put objects, is the batch put faster than putting them one by one?

Another question is, I am putting a very large Put object, which caused the job to fail. There seems a limit on the size of a Put object. How large can it be?

Answer (score 4):

`put(List<Put> puts)` or `put(Put aPut)` are the same under the hood. They both call `doPut(List<Put> puts)`.

What matters is the buffer size as mentioned by @ozhang. e.g. The default value is 2MB.

```
<property>   
     <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
     <value>2097152</value> 
</property>
```

There will be 1 RPC every time the write buffer is filled up and a `flushCommits()` is triggered. So if your application is flushing to often because your objects are relatively big, experimenting with increasing the write buffer size will solve the problem.

Comment: 20971520 is 20 MiB not 2 MiB

Comment: Anyone looking for evidence of `put(List<Put>)` and `put(Put)` being the same: https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/fe146eb48c24d56dbcd2f669bb5ff8197e6c918b/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.java#L1023. Remember to set `autoFlush` to false.

Comment: The default config show the value as **2097152**, not 10 times larger [hbase-default.xml](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/resources/hbase-default.xml)

Answer (score 2):

If your key value size is large, then using list of puts may have a client side buffer size problem.

```
<property>   
    <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
    <value>20971520</value> 
</property>
```

Client collects upto 2mb data by default and then flushes it. So you also have to increase this value

Answer (score 1):

For batch puts it's better if you construct a list of puts and then call `HTableInterface.put(List<Put> puts)` because it uses a single RPC call to commit the batch, but depending on the size of the list write buffer may flush it all or not

Comment: Constructing a list of puts then call `put(List<Put> puts)` doesn't make any different. `put(Put aPut)` and `put(List<Put> puts)` are the same under the hood. They both use `doPut(List<Put> puts)`.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely save on the overhead of multiple RPC requests versus one by using put(List puts) method.

About the very large Put object: there is a limitation by default on maximum KeyValue size of 10MB. I think you have to increase that to store bigger KeyValue objects.

hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize

Specifies the combined maximum allowed size of a KeyValue instance. This is to set an upper boundary for a single entry saved in a storage file. Since they cannot be split it helps avoiding that a region cannot be split any further because the data is too large. It seems wise to set this to a fraction of the maximum region size. Setting it to zero or less disables the check.

Default: 10485760

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is deprecated

> p̶u̶t̶(̶L̶i̶s̶t̶<̶P̶u̶t̶>̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶s̶)̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶(̶P̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶P̶u̶t̶)̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶h̶o̶o̶d̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶b̶o̶t̶h̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶d̶o̶P̶u̶t̶(̶L̶i̶s̶t̶<̶P̶u̶t̶>̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶s̶)̶.̶

There is new implements now.
`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl.SingleServerRequestRunnable#run`
`MultiServerCallable`

> Callable that handles the multi method call going against a single regionserver

So I think the answer for your first question is yes.

I will verify it by benchmark test sometime.