# Flink time buffered sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to write a Flink application which reads events from Kafka, enriches these events from MySQL and writes this data to HBase. I'm doing the MySQL enrichment within a `RichFlatMapFunction` and I'm now trying to figure out how best to write to HBase. I want to batch writes to HBase, so  I'm currently thinking of using a `WindowAll`, followed by a identity `apply` (only to get back to a `DataStream`) and then write a `HBaseSink` which takes a list of records and does batch `Puts` to `HBase`.

Is this the right way to be doing things? It feels weird to be using the `WindowAll` and `apply` just to be doing time based buffering.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see on Jira with [FLINK-2055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2055), I think your best option currently is to use Flink Streaming's [support for Async I/O](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html), and handle buffering inside of that custom function. It appears that the tricky bits come from (a) properly handling checkpoints/retries (atomic puts) and (b) avoiding overloading HBase region servers. But if you aren't worried about exactly-once support, and can tune settings to your HBase setup, then this should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The heaviest operation when dealing with HBase is actually to open a connection to it (as also explained in the documentation: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html).

What I would suggest is to implement another `RichFlatMapFunction` such that you are able to open one connection only once in each Task and then to perform a `Put` to HBase every time an event is required to be persisted.
So far the difference with your current approach will be that:

- you don't require to use a `WindowAll`
- you don't open a new connection to HBase every time in the `HBaseSink`

Regarding the fact of executing the `Put` to HBase from a batch or from a streaming perspective, doesn't actually change the complexity of the operations (as you can also see from the first answer to this question: [Is HBase batch put put(List<Put>) faster than put(Put)? What is the capacity of a Put object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754077/is-hbase-batch-put-putlistput-faster-than-putput-what-is-the-capacity-of) ) so far you will be doing still `N` operations to persist `N` events.

Comment: interesting, thank you. I can also use  `RichSinkFunction` right? That also lets me override the `open` method and I can open the connection only once inside it.

Comment: I don't know about that specifically, but if you want to implement the same as the `RichFlatMapFunction` but in a completely async way, then you can use the `RichAsyncFuntion` as suggested by @kkrugler You can check the docs at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html and then you can open the connection to HBase in the override of the `open()` method.